# File size not updated after write()?

Tags: python, sockets, file-io

In the below code I am trying to receive a file from Python Sockets and write it to a local file
I have following code

```
chunk=clientDtSocket.recv(1024)

while chunk:
    print("In Chunk"+str(chunk))    

    incomingFile.write(chunk)
    chunk=clientDtSocket.recv(1024)
```

I get following

```
In Chunkb'Sohail Khan'
```

But the file size remains same.
Also how can I count the no of bytes I have recieved.

Comment: Have you closed the file? Using just `write` will add content to buffer. You either need to flush or close the file to see actual output

Comment: I got the issue thnx for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the file is closed after the loop.

You can check the received bytes count using `len` function:

```
chunk = clientDtSocket.recv(1024)

while chunk:
    print("received {} bytes".format(len(chunk))) # <-----
    print("In Chunk " + str(chunk))
    incomingFile.write(chunk)
    chunk = clientDtSocket.recv(1024)

incomingFile.close() # <----
```

Instead of manually closing the file, consider using [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement):

```
with open('/path/to/localfile', 'wb') as incomingFile:
    ....
```

Comment: or use `with` and you don't have to worry about closing files

Answer (score -1):

When you open file set write buffer size to 0:

```
bufsize = 0
incomingFile = open('....', 'w', bufsize)
```

It is normal behevior, that data are saved to the file not immidiately after calling write function, but afted write buffer will be totaly filled. But if you setup buffer size to 0 as in axample above, yoor data will be written immidiatel. Writting data from write buffer to file often callaed "flushing"

Flushing also occured when you close file:

```
incomingFile.close()
```